# MYSQL: Trying to count Property_IDs over a close_dt Interval

Tags: mysql, sql

```
select 
pd.state AS StateName, 
pd.county AS `County Name`,

CASE pc.close_dt WHEN pc.close_dt >= DATE(NOW() - INTERVAL 3 MONTH)
THEN COUNT(pd.property_id) 
 ELSE NULL
  END AS `3 MONTH`, 
CASE pc.close_dt WHEN pc.close_dt >= DATE(NOW() - INTERVAL 6 MONTH)
THEN COUNT(pd.property_id) 
 ELSE NULL
  END AS `6 MONTH`
from resnet.property_details pd
join resnet.property_closings pc
    on pd.property_id = pc.Property_id
GROUP BY pd.state,pd.county
```

I'm trying to get the interval of 3 months from today, 6 months from today for properties that have been closed.

[image]

I want it to look like the this:

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need conditional aggregation.  In MySQL, you can do this as:

```
select pd.state AS StateName, pd.county AS `County Name`,
       SUM(pc.close_dt >= CURDATE() - INTERVAL 3 MONTH) AS `3 MONTH`, 
       SUM(pc.close_dt >= CURDATE() - INTERVAL 6 MONTH) AS `6 MONTH`
from resnet.property_details pd join
     resnet.property_closings pc
     on pd.property_id = pc.Property_id
group by pd.state, pd.county;
```

Notes:

- Your `case` syntax just doesn't make sense.  You either have conditions (as  `case when <condition>` or you have constants as `case <column> when <value>`).  But not both.
- `date(now())` = `CURDATE()`.
- You don't need `case` expressions because MySQL treats booleans as integers in a numeric context.  You can just "sum them up" to count the number of true values.

EDIT:

If you want 3-6 months, then you would do:

```
   SUM(pc.close_dt >= CURDATE() - INTERVAL 6 MONTH AND
       pc.close_dt < CURDATE() - INTERVAL 3 MONTH) AS `6 MONTH`
```

Comment: Is INTERVAL 3 MONTH, the same as 0-3 MONTHS. INTERVAL 6 MONTH, the same as 3-6 months?

Comment: I'm not sure if the INTERVAL Logic fits what I need. If I want it to be 3-6 months would I write it as SUM(pc.close_dt >= CURDATE() - INTERVAL 3- 6 MONTH) ??

Comment: @leeTey  . . . Your question is ambiguous as to which you want.  I edited the answer for that version.